# clicking of button is not working after closing and reopening of excel in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA in MS Excel and i need a help though. I've been searching on the web but I haven't find any solution about my problem.

I added a button on my excel and tried to pop up a message after a  button is clicked and it worked perfectly. However, when I closed the excel application, the alert message is not working when button is clicked. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    msgbox ("this is test")
End Sub
```

What shoud I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem may be the file type of excel.

I think that you are saving your workbook as **"Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)"** type.

So, when reopen the workbook, even the button is not disappear, the macro is dismiss. Therefore, when you clicked the button, it shown nothing.

So, rewrite the code and save your workbook as **"Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet (.xlsm)"**. After that, your problem will be solved.

Because, excel macro can only save in that enabled file type. Normal excel type cannot save macro.